# DbContext disposed when running parallel requests to repository

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

After updating to ABP v3.0.0, I started getting `DbContext disposed` exception when running parallel requests to repository that create new `UnitOfWork` like this:

```
using (var uow = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
```

I looked in the source code and found some code in [`AsyncLocalCurrentUnitOfWorkProvider`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/v3.0.0/src/Abp/Domain/Uow/AsyncLocalCurrentUnitOfWorkProvider.cs) that I don't understand. When setting current `uow`, it sets property in wrapper:

```
private static readonly AsyncLocal<LocalUowWrapper> AsyncLocalUow = new AsyncLocal<LocalUowWrapper>();

private static void SetCurrentUow(IUnitOfWork value)
{
    lock (AsyncLocalUow)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            if (AsyncLocalUow.Value == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (AsyncLocalUow.Value.UnitOfWork?.Outer == null)
            {
                AsyncLocalUow.Value.UnitOfWork = null;
                AsyncLocalUow.Value = null;
                return;
            }

            AsyncLocalUow.Value.UnitOfWork = AsyncLocalUow.Value.UnitOfWork.Outer;
        }
        else
        {
            if (AsyncLocalUow.Value?.UnitOfWork == null)
            {
                if (AsyncLocalUow.Value != null)
                {
                    AsyncLocalUow.Value.UnitOfWork = value;
                }

                AsyncLocalUow.Value = new LocalUowWrapper(value);
                return;
            }

            value.Outer = AsyncLocalUow.Value.UnitOfWork;
            AsyncLocalUow.Value.UnitOfWork = value;
        }
    }
}

private class LocalUowWrapper
{
    public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }

    public LocalUowWrapper(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
}
```

That does not look thread-safe, as any thread can set new `UnitOfWork` and then dispose it.

Is it a bug? I can use my own implementation of `ICurrentUnitOfWorkProvider`, without wrapping, but I'm not sure if that is correct.

## Update

I can't give an example with `DbContext disposed` exception, but here is one with `null reference` exception in `repository.GetAll()` method. I think it has the same reason.

```
namespace TestParallelEFRequest
{
    public class Ent1 : Entity<int> { public string Name { get; set; } }
    public class Ent2 : Entity<int> { public string Name { get; set; } }
    public class Ent3 : Entity<int> { public string Name { get; set; } }
    public class Ent4 : Entity<int> { public string Name { get; set; } }
    public class DomainStartEvent : EventData {}
    public class DBContext : AbpDbContext {
        public DBContext(): base("Default") {}
        public IDbSet<Ent1> Ent1 { get; set; }
        public IDbSet<Ent2> Ent2 { get; set; }
        public IDbSet<Ent3> Ent3 { get; set; }
        public IDbSet<Ent4> Ent4 { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestService : DomainService, IEventHandler<DomainStartEvent>
    {
        private readonly IRepository<Ent1> _rep1;
        private readonly IRepository<Ent2> _rep2;
        private readonly IRepository<Ent3> _rep3;
        private readonly IRepository<Ent4> _rep4;
        public TestService(IRepository<Ent1> rep1, IRepository<Ent2> rep2, IRepository<Ent3> rep3, IRepository<Ent4> rep4) { 
                _rep1 = rep1;_rep2 = rep2;_rep3 = rep3;_rep4 = rep4;
        }

        Task HandleEntityes<T>(IRepository<T> rep, int i) where T : class, IEntity<int> {
            return Task.Run(() => {
                using (var uow = UnitOfWorkManager.Begin(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew)) {
                    Thread.Sleep(i); // Simulating work
                    rep.GetAll();    // <- Exception here
                }
            });
        }

        public void HandleEvent(DomainStartEvent eventData) {
            using (var uow = UnitOfWorkManager.Begin(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew)) {
                var t1 = HandleEntityes(_rep1, 10);
                var t2 = HandleEntityes(_rep2, 10);
                var t3 = HandleEntityes(_rep3, 10);
                var t4 = HandleEntityes(_rep4, 1000);
              Task.WaitAll(t1, t2, t3, t4);
            }
        }
    }

    [DependsOn(typeof(AbpEntityFrameworkModule))]
    public class ProgrammModule : AbpModule
    {
        public override void PreInitialize() { Configuration.DefaultNameOrConnectionString = "Default"; }
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            Database.SetInitializer<DBContext>(null);
        }
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            using (var bootstrapper = AbpBootstrapper.Create<ProgrammModule>()) {
                bootstrapper.Initialize();
                bootstrapper.IocManager.Resolve<IEventBus>().Trigger(new DomainStartEvent());
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, you'r right. But an entity can not be shared by multiple DbContexts and multiple transactions. This is an exception of Entity Framework.

Comment: You may try adding the Enlist=false parameter to your connection string. This would disable automatic enlisting in a distributed transaction

Comment: i dont need to share entity by different multiple context. i have different entities and i want to parallel handling in different dbcontext of it and then agregate the result. 
        var tInOut = GetInOutBatches(procedure.Id);
        var tInOutGroup = GetInOutGroups(procedure.Id);
        var tProcess = GetBaseProcess(procedure.BaseProcessId);
        var tOperations = GetOperations(procedure.Id);
        await Task.WhenAll(tInOut, tInOutGroup, tProcess, tOperations);

Comment: can you share us your implementation to overcome this issue?

Comment: What's `null` in the null reference exception?

Comment: Exception throws on `ActiveDbContexts[dbContextKey] = dbContext;` in EfUnitOfWork class. it works ok, if change ActiveDbContexts from `Dicrionary` to `ConcurrentDictionary`

Comment: This is an open issue: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2211